# Javascript or jQuery slider where active slide gets bigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

Javascript or jQuery slider where active slide gets bigger Javascript or jQuery slider where active slide gets bigger Javascript or jQuery slider where active slide gets bigger Javascript or jQuery slider where active slide gets bigger Javascript or jQuery slider where active slide gets bigger

Answer (score 1):

The last time I used sliders [BX Slider](http://bxslider.com/) was quite good.

Edit: You could also try http://flexslider.woothemes.com/ (recommended)

What you could do though is use any slider, so long as that slider gives the active slide a class (e.g. .active), you could then style it in the way you need. For the animation of the active slide to scale/shrink you can you CSS.

```
.slide { transition: all .2s ease-in-out; }
.slide.active { transform: scale(1.1); }
```

You will probably find it easier to do it this way, than finding a **good** slider plugin that fulfills your needs.

Comment: i actually tried bxSlider, it fails in setting up the basic slider at all, there is just one image and a big blank space. minSlider Option does not work at all.

Comment: flexslider is even worse.

Comment: even worse at what? if you are struggling to get them to work at all, I would suggest reading over their documentation.

Comment: both only work in “carousel” with fixed width (which is not documented, or i didn't see it), when in carousel there is no active slide anymore.

Comment: Your idea works perfectly with cycle2carousel!
http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle2/demo/carousel.php
you only have to use the cycle-before event to move the active slide to the center of your slider since they always consider the first slide visible the active one.